# Сложение двух Date

Tags: java, android

У меня две даты типа String, первый в формате `"yyyy.MM.dd"`, второй `"HH:mm"`

Их перевел в тип `Date` с помощью `SimpleDateFormat`;

Так вот, мне нужно их сложить, то есть чтобы результат был `"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm"`

Есть ли другие варианты как их сложить, кроме

```
date.setHours();
date.setMinutes();
```

Comment: Дата не бывает "в формате". Формат бывает у строки. Определитесь, что у Вас есть и что Вам нужно

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Обновил вопрос. Теперь думаю будет понятно

Comment: Сложить - это именно date1+date2 или же строковые представления даты сконкатенировать?

Comment: Да, второе, то есть если первый 2018.02.15, и второй 22:20, то в результате было 2018.02.15 22:20

Comment: Если Вам нужно сконкатенировать строки, то зачем их переводить в дату?

Comment: Я настолько никогда не тупил). Спасибо. Короче, я должен удалить вопрос)

Answer (score 2):

Если требуется просто конкантенация строк, зачем переводить строку в Date, чтобы потом опять приводить её к строке?

Просто складывайте как строки:

```
System.out.println(String1 + " " + String2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть ли у данного Класс фабрика через String, если да то....

```
Date3.fromString(Date1.toString() + " " + Date2.toString());
```